# String check always returns false Palidrome

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program to check if an input string from the user is a palindrome
My program always returns false even if the string is a known palindrome.
I think my problem lies in the PalindromeChecker function in that this is what always sets the answer variable in the main function to false. However I am unsure as to why this is always the case.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <String>

using namespace std;

char ReadPalIn(string Pal, int len)//converts the string into a char array
{
    char PalIn[100];
    if (len > 100)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Palindrome possibliity too big" << endl;
        system("Pause");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            PalIn[i] = Pal[i];
        }
    }
    return *PalIn;
}

bool PalindromeChecker(char Pal[],int start, int end)//checks recursively if a string is a palidrome
{
    if (start == end)
    {
        return true; //since there is only one character
    }
    else if (Pal[start] != Pal[end])
    {
        //cout << "hi" << endl;
        return false;//since that will be the case that decides when something stops being a palidrome
    }
    else if (start < end + 1)
    {
        //cout << "hi" << endl;
        return PalindromeChecker(Pal, start++, end--);//since we checked both the first and last characters of the char array for palandrominess. <- word of the year?
    }
    else
    {
        return true;//base case is the string is a palindrome
    }
}

int main()//test if a word is a palidrome using the functions
{
    int lengthOfPal = 0;
    string PalInd = "abba";
    bool Answer = true;
    cout << "Hello what string would you like to check?" << endl;
    getline(cin, PalInd);
    lengthOfPal = PalInd.length();
    cout << "You input is: " << PalInd << endl;
    cout << "Its Length is: " << lengthOfPal << endl;
    system("Pause");
    char PalIn[100] = { ReadPalIn(PalInd, lengthOfPal) };

    Answer = PalindromeChecker(PalIn, 0, lengthOfPal);
    if (Answer == true)
    {
        cout << PalInd << ": is a palidrome" << endl;
        system("Pause");
    }
    else if(Answer == false)
    {
        //cout << "hi" << endl;
        cout << PalInd << ": is not a palidrome" << endl;
        system("Pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: Why are you torturing yourself with char arrays? You know how to use `std::string`, which manages the memory stuff for you. Your problem is in your `ReadPalIn` function. It returns a single character (the first one in the string). You then try to assign the character to a char array. Always use `std::string` when you can so you don't have to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: You can read the underlying char array of a `std::string` with `PalInd.c_str()`

Comment: You can't return a pointer to a local variable from a function.

Answer (score 1):

You're always returning `false` because you're not comparing what you think you're comparing.

On the initial call to `PalindromeChecker()`, you're using `lengthOfPal` as the `end` argument. Being that strings are zero-indexed, your initial call should be using `lengthOfPal - 1`.

Assume your string is `abba`. The `a` characters are located at `[0]` and `[s.length() - 1]` (index `[3]`).

Another issue you're going to end up having is passing `start++` and `end--` as arguments in the recursive calls. Those are post-increment and post-decrement operators, which means its going to pass the *current* value of `start` and `end` into the recursive call, and *then* adjust their values. Since you've set the function up to be recursive, it will just keep using the same value for `start` and `end` every time. Use pre-increment `++start` and pre-decrement `--end` instead to avoid this issue.